# tmux: Is possible add/remove the smcup and rmcup capabilities in the current session?

Tags: tmux

I have the following configuration in `.tmux.conf` to switch off and on the smcup/rmcup capabilities.

```
set -g terminal-overrides ',xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
bind-key ñ set -g terminal-overrides ',xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
bind-key Ñ set -U terminal-overrides ',xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
```

The above configuration does work but only if a open a new session.
Is there a way to apply that on the current session?